# What's the simplest way to generate code model in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, model

I'm looking for the simplest way to generate code model in C++. What I basically mean:

- input is a file with C++ code (.cpp) or its content;
- output could be either call tree with names of all functions/methods, OR just list of all methods being called from this C++ file. Important hint is that I need list of all parameters being passed to these functions (for every occurrence in the file).

I heard that clang library could do something like this, but does anybody know where to start from? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at [libTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) which is a clang API to create clang based tools.

LibTooling lets you directly manipulate the ASTs by creating frontend actions which can be overridden (take a look here: http://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/).

By walking through the AST you can easily generate the information you're searching for. Notice that if your code contains macros you might also need a preprocessing action. Use clang's `-ast-dump` option to help you out in understanding your AST structure. Good luck.

Comment: Try Doxygen.  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/   Even without descriptive comments it produces useful output, and it's a good practice to get into properly documenting any code that you write or maintain to help "the next guy" understand it.

Comment: doxygen might be another viable alternative but you need to be comfortable with its output (more document-oriented and less customizable), otherwise you will need to work on its output and/or modify doxygen's code by yourself

Comment: Agreed, but when I read the question it appears that the OP wants documentation, not an AST.  "list all methods being called"  "list of all parameters."

Comment: @suryadeva, could you clarify whether you want the program documented or whether you want input into an object modeling tool.  If the latter, most tools will let you reverse engineer existing code.

Comment: if the "list of all parameters being passed to these functions (for every occurrence in the file" means analyzing the body of the functions, there's no way doxygen can do it and so he will need clang. Otherwise, it's up to the OP